# How to create Adobe Air application from an existing FLASH8 project?

Tags: flash, air

Is there any simple way how to pack existing Flash8 project using AS2 and multiple files to to Adobe Air application?

Comment: Would a projector for as2 do the job (e.g. Screenweaver ( http://screenweaver.org/doku.php?id=docs:as_api ), mProjector ( http://www.screentime.com/software/flash-projector/flas.html ) or zinc ( http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/ ) ) ?

Comment: no... I'm interested in AIR to be able get our old game to Blackberry PlayBook using AIR SDK.

Answer (score 1):

So far this is minimum app.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5">
  <id>my.app.id</id>
  <versionNumber>1.0</versionNumber>
  <filename>test-app</filename>
  <description/>
  <name>Test AIR app</name>
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>test.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>auto</renderMode>
    <width>646</width>
    <height>468</height>
    <maximizable>true</maximizable>
    <minimizable>true</minimizable>
    <resizable>false</resizable>
  </initialWindow>
  <icon/>
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <installFolder>Test AIR app</installFolder>
  <programMenuFolder>Test AIR app</programMenuFolder>
</application>
```

where test.swf can be FLASH8 project.. The true is, there are some differences which I must investigate. I don't believe that there is no solution.

UPDATE:
So it looks the main difference is, how are used relative paths <s>for shared content</s>..
For example lets say I have such a file structure:

```
main.swf
data/level1.swf
data/shared_content.swf
```

Then when I want to *importAssets* from shared_content.swf into level1.swf, which is loaded from main.swf, in Flash player I use path '**data/shared_content.swf**', but for AIR I must use just '**shared_content.swf**'. It means in AIR the path is not relative to root SWF file, but to the file which is importing.

The rest seems to be working so far.. I will update again if I find some other difference.

Answer (score 0):

In other than simplest case, **no**. AS2 scripts are misbehaving when loaded into AIR app (which is always AS3). Some issues I've seen: Stage.width and Stage.height is always 0, *sometimes* Mouse.addListener doesn't work, mouse wheel may not work. The more complex are scripts, the more errors will arise.